# Cannot build .tex file

Tags: fonts, miktex, compiling, texmaker, greek

I am running `MikTex 2.9` and I'm facing a problem. When i try to edit a tex file it keeps building for ever. I've noticed that in Task Manager there is a process that's running, `miktex-maketfm.exe`.

Also, the dialog box in Texmaker says that

```
Process started

pdflatex

: Unknown archive file size. pdflatex: Data: cbfonts-fd
```

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext\latintext#1}
\begin{document}
        \eng{This is the $1^{st}$ \LaTeX{} document!}\\
        Το πρώτο κείμενο \LaTeX!
        Φαίνεται πως δουλεύει!
        υπομονή
\end{document}
```

I've also installed the following packages : `greek-inputenc`,`greek-fontenc`.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try to install cbfonts-fd with the package manager. If there are errors: Change the repository and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: With your help the problem is solved! Thank you very much!! :)
Could you post it as an answer for others to be able to see it clearly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to install cbfonts-fd with the package manager. If there are errors: Change the repository and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which you can try:

- Try restarting your system
- Check the build options in : > Tex -> Configure Texmaker
- Try building in some other format like DVI or PS

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that the problem was the missing package `cbfonts-fd`!